# Making a comments system in rarebit

Tags: javascript, html

I recently started a webcomic using [rarebit](https://www.rarebit.neocities.org). However, I want to add a comments system. The problem with this is that each strip does not have its own page, but the data from that strip is pulled using a js script on index.html. (works out what comic it is supposed to be showing, gets the data for it and then displays it using more functions. I guess the way to do it would be to store the comments in the pages data, which looks like this:

```
`{

pgNum: 2,

title: "title",

date: writeDate([YEAR],[MONTH],[DAY]),

altText: "alt text",

imageFiles: "no. of image files in that strip",

authorNotes: \`
    <p>notes go here>/p>
    `

},`
```

I guess I would store comments here, but have no idea how to do it(don't know js). Thank you for any help!

Link to webcomic for reference: [https://ahumanibelieve.github.io/](https://www.ahumanibelieve.github.io)

I thought having normal comment code would work, but then I realised that since every strip is in one html file, it wouldn't work

Comment: There are some issues you need to address before figuring out what to implement (and how to do it). Some of these are: how would the visitors input their comments? How would you prevent one person from spamming the page with nonsensical or harmful content? Where would you store the comments? How would you parse the visitor inputs before storing them for future retrieval? Should the comments be displayed one beneath the other, or should they be nested?  etc. If you have no experience with JS, I'd suggest using something like WordPress, since it seems it would suit your needs better.

Comment: I know, but I want to host on github pages as it is the easiest solution for me. Believe me, I want to use WP, but I don't want to pay for a server, and then a URL. I'd much rather just use the free one provided by github.